# How to avoid Spark and Hive log from Application log

Tags: java, logging, log4j, apache-spark, hdfs

I would like to learn how to avoid Spark and Hive log from Application log. I mean both spark and hive are using log4j property file.

I have configured log4j.property file as per my application as under but it's printing Spark and hive console logging also. I am running application in HDFS environment.

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,debugLog, SplLog

log4j.appender.debugLog=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.debugLog.File=logs/Debug.log
log4j.appender.debugLog.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.debugLog.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.debugLog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.debugLog.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1} - %m%n
log4j.appender.debugLog.filter.f1=org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter
log4j.appender.debugLog.filter.f1.LevelMax=DEBUG
log4j.appender.debugLog.filter.f1.LevelMin=DEBUG

log4j.appender.SplLog=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.SplLog.File=logs/AppSplCmd.log
log4j.appender.SplLog.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.SplLog.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.SplLog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.SplLog.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1} - %m%n
log4j.appender.SplLog.filter.f1=org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter
log4j.appender.SplLog.filter.f1.LevelMax=FATAL
log4j.appender.SplLog.filter.f1.LevelMin=INFO

log4j.logger.debugLogger=DEBUG, debugLog
log4j.additivity.debugLogger=false

log4j.logger.AppSplLogger=INFO, SplLog
log4j.additivity.AppSplLogger=false
```

Comment: How are you running your Spark job? Is it in Spark Shell? From your IDE? Using spark-submit (client or cluster mode)?

Comment: spark shell Using spark-submit (client or cluster mode)

Comment: Alright, so your building a fat Jar with your classes and librairies. 
Is your log4j.properties taken into account (Debug.log, AppSplCmd.log created)?
Which libraries do you place in the Jar (mvn dependency:list or sbt )?

Comment: its maven dependency, I created to log debug in separate file and special commands in separate

Comment: Are the Debug.log, AppSplCmd.log created?

Answer (score 2):

Raise the rootLogger level:

```
log4j.rootLogger=WARN,debugLog,SplLog
```

Or at least, set the `org.apache` logger level (without this config Spark and Hive loggers use the rootLogger config):

```
log4j.logger.org.apache=WARN
```